# Android: OnClickListener, OnTouchListener crashes

Tags: android, layout, view, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I wanted to test how to change views dinamycally on Android, without starting another activity.

So I wrote this code and it crashed whenever I implemented OnTouchListener and OnClickListener together but if I used just one of them, it worked fine (although it didnt do what I wanted it to do).

```
public class Test extends Activity implements OnTouchListener, OnClickListener {

ImageView image;
Button ret;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.displaytest);

    image = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image01);
    ret = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.ret);

    image.setOnTouchListener(this);
    ret.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();

    switch(action)
    {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        setContentView(R.layout.returnd);
        break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    setContentView(R.layout.displaytest);
}
```

}

Basically, I just wanted to display a picture and when the user touched it, change the view to display a button that lets you go back to the main view.

By the way, I'm new to Android, so I think it should be a pretty lame error. Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please show the output of the error from the LogCat. It's hard to tell where it is going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Please remove setContentView() methods in onTouch & onCLick event.Its causing the problem.You can't set content view multiple times in activity. You can see dynamic changes in ui using any other methods, like change text in textVIew, changing color or changing images in imageview etc..

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can call `setContentView` multiple times like that.

You should have the button invisible in the layout, and make it visibile when the picture is touched, instead of loading a new layout.

Answer (score 0):

Without the stack Trace (logcat) you won't get any quality answer.

BTW: New layout = new Activity (or Fragment).
**NOT** setContentView()

Period.